# How to fire jQuery on an element only when it's loaded?

Tags: jquery

I seem to be stuck here. I have an HTML page loading content dynamically—one of the "pages" loaded contains an accordion presenting the paragraphs on click.

Now I would like to implement the corresponding JavaScript / jQuery to make the accordion work. So far I had implemented the jQuery in the footer—problem is, that it would look for elements that are not loaded yet. This is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#acc1", function(){
    jQuery(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast");
})
```

This does work perfectly fine when opening a "static" url for that page—but not if the page is loaded dynamically. The `#acc1` isn't loaded when the jQuery is loaded—so it can't be bound to that id yet. I hope I made my problem clear? Thank you very much! I would appreciate all suggestions / pointers …

Comment: Why don't you just use the accordion plugin of JQuery ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/